# How to extract key value pairs from a file when values span multiple lines?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I'm a few weeks into bash scripting and I haven't advanced enough yet to get my head wrapped around this problem.  Any help would be appreciated!

I have a "**script.conf**" file that contains the following:

```
key1=value1
key2=${HOME}/Folder
key3=( "k3v1" "k3 v2" "k3v3")
key4=( "k4v1"
    "k4 v2"
    "k4v3"
)
key5=value5
#key6="Do Not Include Me"
```

In a bash script, I want to read the contents of this script.conf file into an array.  I've learned how to handle the scenarios for keys 1, 2, 3, and 5, but the **key4 scenario** throws a wrench into it with it spanning across multiple lines.

I've been exploring the use of `sed -n '/=\s*[(]/,/[)]/{/'` which does capture key4 and its value, but I can't figure out how to mix this so that the other keys are also captured in the matches.  The range syntax is also new to me, so I haven't figured out how to separate the key/value.  I feel like there is an easy regex that would accomplish what I want... in plain-text: "find and group the pattern `^(.*)=` (for the key), then group everything after the '=' char until another `^(.*)=` match is found, rinse and repeat".  I guess if I do this, I need to change the while read line to not handle the key/value separation for me (I'll be looking into this while I'm waiting for a response).  BTW, I think a solution where the value of key4 is flattened (new lines removed) would be acceptable; I know for key3 I have to store the value as a string and then convert it to an array later when I want to iterate over it since an array element apparently can't contain a list.

Am I on the right path with `sed` or is this a job for `awk` or some other tool? (I haven't ventured into awk yet).  Is there an easier approach that I'm missing because I'm too deep into the forest (like changing the `while read` line in the LoadConfigFile function)?

Here is the code that I have so far in **script.sh** for processing and capturing the other pairs into the $config array:

```
__AppDir=$(dirname $0)
__AppName=${__ScriptName%.*}


typeset -A config   #init config array
config=(    #Setting Default Config values
    [key1]="defaultValue1"
    [key2]="${HOME}/defaultFolder"

    [QuietMode]=0
    [Verbose]=0     #Ex. Usage: [[ "${config[Verbose]}" -gt 0 ]] && echo ">>>Debug print"
)

function LoadConfigFile() {
    local cfgFile="${1}"
    shopt -s extglob    #Needed to remove trailing spaces
    if [ -f ${cfgFile} ]; then
        while IFS='=' read -r key value; do
            if [[ "${key:0:1}" == "#" ]]; then
                #echo "Skipping Comment line: ${key}"
            elif [ "${key:-EMPTY}" != "EMPTY" ]; then
                value="${value%%\#*}"   # Delete in-line, right comments
                value="${value%%*( )}"  # Delete trailing spaces
                value="${value%%( )*}"  # Delete leading spaces
                #value="${value%\"*}"   # Delete opening string quotes
                #value="${value#\"*}"   # Delete closing string quotes

                #Manipulate any variables included in the value so that they can be expanded correctly 
                #  - value must be stored in the format: "${var1}".  `backticks`, "$var2", and "doubleQuotes" are left as is
                value="${value//\"/\\\"}"    # Escape double quotes for eval
                value="${value//\`/\\\`}"    # Escape backticks for eval
                value="${value//\$/\\\$}"    # Escape ALL '$' for eval
                value="${value//\\\${/\${}" # Undo the protection of '$' if it was followed by a '{'        
                value=$(eval "printf '%s\n' \"${value}\"")

                config[${key}]=${value} #Store the value into the config array at the specified key                 
                echo "  >>>DBG: Key = ${key}, Value = ${value}"
            #else
            #   echo "Skipped Empty Key"
            fi

        done < "${cfgFile}"
    fi
}

CONFIG_FILE=${__AppDir}/${__AppName}.conf
echo "Config File @ ${CONFIG_FILE}"

LoadConfigFile ${CONFIG_FILE}

#Print elements of $config
echo "Script Config Values:"
echo "----------------------------"
for key in "${!config[@]}"; do      #The '!' char gets an array of the keys, without it, we would get an array of the values
    printf "  %-20s = %s\n" "${key}" "${config[${key}]}"
done
echo "------ End Script Config ------"

#To convert to an array...
declare -a valAsArray=${config[RequiredAppPackages]}    #Convert the value from a string to an array
echo "Count = ${#valAsArray[@]}"
for itemCfg in "${valAsArray[@]}"; do
    echo "  item = ${itemCfg}"
done
```

As I mentioned before, I'm just starting to learn bash and Linux scripting in general, so if you see that I'm doing some taboo things in other areas of my code too, please feel free to provide feedback in the comments... I don't want to start bad habits early on :-).

*If it matters, the OS is Ubuntu 14.04.

**EDIT:**
As requested, after reading the script.conf file, I would like for the elements in `$config[@]` to be equivalent to the following:

```
typeset -A config   #init config array
config=(    
    [key1]="value1"
    [key2]="${HOME}/Folder"
    [key3]="( \"k3v1\" \"k3 v2\" \"k3v3\" )"
    [key4]="( \"k4v1\" \"k4 v2\" \"k4v3\" )"
    [key5]="value5"
)
```

I want to be able to convert the values of elements 'key4' and 'key3' into an array and iterated over them the same way in the following code:

```
declare -a keyValAsArray=${config[keyN]}    #Convert the value from a string to an array
echo "Count = ${#keyValAsArray[@]}"
for item in "${keyValAsArray[@]}"; do
    echo "  item = ${item}"
done
```

I don't think it matters if \n is preserved for key4's value or not... that depends on if `declare` has a problem with it.

Comment: Is sourcing the config file not an option?

Comment: Instead of implementing a buggy subset of a bash parser, why don't you just _source_ the file?

Comment: Are you constrained using the shell? For such tasks I'd use a different *language* (python, perl, ...)

Comment: @LevLevitsky From what I've learned, sourcing a config file should be avoided for security reasons (don't execute code).  It might be what I have to resort to though.

Comment: @EdMorton I am attempting to load a config file into a shell script so that I can change the flow of automating calls to various tools... and also to provide an easy way to change the parameters that are sent to those tools without the user having to enter a very long list of arguments each time.  My goal was to support a config file so that when starting the automation script, they user could just point to the config file... 1 arg vs many args

Comment: Unless you expect someone to be going into the file to write malicious commands( which why would they as they can just execute them anyway), then sourcing the file is not a security concern.

Comment: @EdMorton sorry about that... forgot to escape the quotes on the elements in the string that should be converted into an array.  It has been fixed.

Comment: @123 speaking as someone whose web site has been hacked from time to time by people uploading files that replaced my existing files and wreaked havoc when innocently accessed later - it happens. Just because someone can write to a file doesn't mean they can execute a command, but they can leave a nice bomb for you to execute later.

Answer (score 1):

A shell is an environment from which to call tools with a language to sequence those calls. It is NOT a tool to manipulate text. The standard UNIX tool to manipulate text is awk. Trying to manipulate text in shell IS a bad habit, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-pr‌​actice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice_) for SOME of the reasons why

You still didn't post the expected result of populating the config array so I'm not sure but I think this is what you wanted:

```
$ cat tst.sh
declare -A config="( $(awk '
    { gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|([[:space:]]+|#.*)$/,"") }
    !NF { next }
    /^[^="]+=/ {
        name = gensub(/=.*/,"",1)
        value = gensub(/^[^=]+=/,"",1)
        n2v[name] = value
        next
    }
    { n2v[name] = n2v[name] OFS $0 }
    END {
        for (name in n2v) {
            value = gensub(/"/,"\\\\&","g",n2v[name])
            printf "[%s]=\"%s\"\n", name, value
        }
    }
    ' script.conf
) )"

declare -p config

$ ./tst.sh
declare -A config='([key5]="value5" [key4]="( \"k4v1\" \"k4 v2\" \"k4v3\" )" [key3]="( \"k3v1\" \"k3 v2\" \"k3v3\")" [key2]="/home/Ed/Folder" [key1]="value1" )'
```

The above uses GNU awk for gensub(), with other awks you'd use [g]sub() instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I haven't had a chance to try out your code yet... hopefully this afternoon.  If everything works out as I need, I'll be back to mark this as the correct answer.  If not, I'll try to be more clear with an example of what I need.

Comment: Close, but not quite what I need.  I'm working on another edit that hopefully will be more clear.

Comment: It might be time for a whole new followup question as this one's already kinda muddy and I doubt if anyone else is still looking at it.

Comment: I've re-written the question to eliminate the "fluff".  If you still advise that I submit a new question, I will.  Thanks again for your help so far.

Comment: I do because otherwise you'll probably only have me reading it and maybe other people will have different/better ideas on how to help you with your new requirements. I'd roll this question back to what it was, accept my answer, then post a new question that stands alone but also references this question just for background.